# Django StreamingHttpResponse deleting file after user finishes downloading it

Tags: python, django

I am having problem tracking when a file download has been completed when StreamingHttpResponse is used. My intention is to delete the file once it has been downloaded by the user.

Doing the following returned an exception in terminal killing the server.

```
def down(request, file_name):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        if file_name:
            import os
            fh = get_object_or_404(FileHandler, filename=file_name)
            csv_path = os.path.join(fh.path, fh.filename)
            csv_file = open(csv_path)
            response = StreamingHttpResponse(csv_file, content_type='text/csv')
            response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="{}"'.format(fh.filename)
            csv_file.close()
            # I can now delete the file using os.remove(csv_path). Not sure since response has not been returned
            return response
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/b2b/export/')
```

Trace back:

```
----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 59899)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 599, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 334, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "/Users/Michael/.virtualenvs/scrape/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 102, in __init__
    super(WSGIRequestHandler, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 655, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "/Users/Michael/.virtualenvs/scrape/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 182, in handle
    handler.run(self.server.get_app())
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 92, in run
    self.close()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/simple_server.py", line 33, in close
    self.status.split(' ',1)[0], self.bytes_sent
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'
----------------------------------------
```

What works is as follows but am not sure when to delete the file or know when download has been completed. Most importantly how to close the file:

```
def down(request, file_name):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        if file_name:
            import os
            fh = get_object_or_404(FileHandler, filename=file_name)
            csv_path = os.path.join(fh.path, fh.filename)

            response = StreamingHttpResponse(open(csv_path), content_type='text/csv')
            response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="{}"'.format(fh.filename)
            return response
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/b2b/export/')
```

Answer (score 2):

I have tried the above suggestion by @mwag; however with FileWrapper.

In my case, wanted to zip up directories and get rid of the archive when download is done.

```
import os, time, zipfile
from django.http import StreamingHttpResponse
from wsgiref.util import FileWrapper

class FileDeleteWrapper(FileWrapper):
    def __init__(self, filepath, *args, **kwargs):
        self.filepath = filepath
        super(FileDeleteWrapper, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def __del__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        os.remove(self.filepath)
# View function
def zipFiles(request, assetId):
    asset = get_object_or_404(Asset, id=assetId)
    try:
        files = File.objects.filter(asset=asset)
        prefix = str(time.time()) +'_'

        zipPath = os.path.join(
            settings.ZIPPED_FILES_DIR,
            prefix + asset.label+'.zip'
        )

        z = zipfile.ZipFile(zipPath, 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)

        for f in files:
            path = os.path.join(
                mainSet.MEDIA_ROOT,
                str(f.file)
            )
            z.write(path, str(f))
        z.close()

        chunkSize = 16384

        response = StreamingHttpResponse(
            FileDeleteWrapper(
                filepath = zipPath,
                filelike=open(zipPath, 'rb'),
                blksize=chunkSize
            )
        )
        response['Content-Length'] = os.path.getsize(zipPath)
        response['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment; filename=%s" % asset.label+'.zip'
        return response
    except Exception as e:
            if mainSet.DEBUG:
                print(type(e))
            else:
                # log expception
                raise Http404
```

Answer (score 1):

Try creating a class that will delete the file when it is gc'd. For example, something like the below might work:

```
class open_then_delete(object):
    def __init__(self, filename, mode='rb'):
        self.filename = filename
        self.file_obj = open(filename, mode)

    def __del__(self):
        self.close()


    def close(self):
        if self.file_obj:
           self.file_obj.close()
           self.file_obj = None
        self.cleanup()

    def cleanup(self):
        if self.filename:
            try:
                sys.stderr.write('open_then_delete: del ' + self.filename)
                os.remove(self.filename)
            except:
                pass
            self.filename = None

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        return getattr(self.file_obj, attr)

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.file_obj)

# below is your code, modified to use use_then_delete
def down(request, file_name):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        if file_name:
            import os
            fh = get_object_or_404(FileHandler, filename=file_name)
            csv = open_then_delete(os.path.join(fh.path, fh.filename))

            response = StreamingHttpResponse(csv.open(), content_type='text/csv')
            response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="{}"'.format(fh.filename)
            return response
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/b2b/export/')
```